# Fraction not simplifying -- potential precision error

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following fraction

[image]

which in principle can be simplified such that the term (constant + $\omega$) cancels on the top and bottom. Mathematica is not doing so and I'm guessing it's an issue with the precision of my numbers.

How can I address this? Ideally I think I would want to cut off the precision of the large number in the denominator. How can I specifically do it for that number only?

Comment: What would you expect/want as the simplification?

Comment: By multiplying the top by 1/0.72 to simplify it, I want the final result to be 0.36 (which is 0.72/2)

Comment: Please include code as text, not pictures.

Comment: In fact, it does not reduce as you think: `84852.8/0.72 // InputForm` shows that the constant on top is `117851.11111111111`, not `117851.`.  The Front End, by default shows only six digits (controlled by `PrintPrecision`), so what you looks the same, but they're not.

Answer (score 3):

You can get any precision you want by using exact numbers.

```
expr = 1/2 (-((848528/10)/(-117851 + ω)) + (72/100 ω)/(-117851 + ω)) // Simplify // Factor
(*(9 ω - 1060660)/(25 (ω - 117851))*)
```

You can then look at decimal precision

```
% // N // Expand // Together
(*(0.36 (1. ω - 117851.))/(ω - 117851.)*)
```

From this view it looks like the terms involving `ω` should cancel, but Mathematica knows better.  Look at

```
expr // N[#, 20] & // Expand // Together
(0.3600000000000000000 (1.000000000000000000 ω - 117851.1111111111111))/(ω - 117851.00000000000000)
```

showing they clearly do not cance\l.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you answered your own question. There is a precision issue. But you can correct in this way:

```
e = 1/2 (-84852.72/(-117851. + x) + (0.72 x)/(-117851. + x));
Rationalize[e] // Simplify
(*9/25*)
```

One lesson from this is to perform analytical calculations as far as possible and substitute numerical values as late as possible. Imagine that all your numbers were some constants, like `a`, `b`, `c` and so on.

Comment: How did you go from 84852.8 to 84852.72? Trial and error? Or some programmatic method? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulCommentary Just a multiplication: $117851.\times 0.72=84852.72$.